# Unable to get ABMutableMultiValueRef in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing a small project working with AddressBook and I'm having a difficult time finding an answer to this issue.

In Obj-C creating a mutable multivalue property looks like this:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAddress = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
```

But in Swift, going about it the same way, I get an error:

```
var multiAddress : ABMutableMultiValueRef = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType)
```

The error reads "'Int' is not convertible to 'ABPropertyType'." Am I bonking some silly syntax mistake or what exactly is the difference here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `ABPropertyType` is a type aliased `UInt32`, while all the constants like `kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType` are defined as `Int`. In Swift you can't use one in place of the other without converting -- this should do the trick:

```
var multiAddress = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType))
```

That will get you an instance of `Unmanaged<ABMutableMultiValue>!`.